# Do the temperatures indicate my laptop healthy?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, cooling, thinkpad, temperature

The temperatures of my Thinkpad T400 are:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
CPU_0:        +57.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
CPU_1:        +56.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Fan:                                                   2939 RPM
CPU neighbourhood (also via ACPI THM0):                 +57.0°C  
Ultrabay:                                               +51.0°C  
Express card:                                           +38.0°C  
ATI graphics module:                                    +73.0°C  
Main battery (always around 50°C):                     +36.0°C  
n/a (probably ultrabay battery):                            N/A  
Main Battery (fits about the value reported by smapi):  +33.0°C  
n/a (probably ultrabay battery):                            N/A  
Hard disc:                                              +40.0°C  
Intel graphics module:                                  +48.0°C  
Heatsink?:                                              +46.0°C  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A  
n/a:                                                        N/A
```

I wonder why ATI graphics module has the highest temperature  +73.0°C?

Do the temperatures indicate my laptop healthy? Do I have to worry about them?

What steps shall I take to make it healthy?

Note: They are achieved when I use a cooler and scale the cpu frequency to the lowest 0.8GHz. WIthout a cooler, the highest temperature will be over 80 celcius. If further without cpu freq scaling, the highest can be 90 and 100 celcius.

Thanks.

Comment: 73 isn't bad at all, unless you're only editing excel spreadsheets or surfing. Make sure the airflow is dust-free, strip the heatsink & replace the thermal paste with high-quality if in any doubt [not a job for a beginner]

Comment: (1) How high temperatures will I need to worry about? (2) the reported temperatures are when I am opening 100 tabs in chrome browser now. They are achieved when I use a cooler and scale the cpu frequency to the lowest 0.8GHz. WIhtout a cooler, the highest temperature will be over 80 celcius. If further without cpu freq scaling, the highest can be 90 and 100 celcius.

Comment: 1) I'd reallyworry at 100; but I would have done something about it long before that. 2) Chrome will eat CPU, not GPU. Only the front-most window should eat GPU, eg if it's running video [& still not much] CPU frequency has no bearing on it. Cheap thermal paste has a lot to answer for.

Comment: Is "ATI graphics module" GPU? How can I scale GPU frequency under ubuntu?

Comment: idk, sorry. Never used Ubuntu.

Comment: Without cpu freq scaling, the max is achieved by CPU. I guess "ATI graphics module" is GPU?

Comment: GPU == Graphical processing Unit == "ATI graphics module"

Comment: Try installing the FGLRX driver.My laptop idled at 65C before installing and after installing it idles at 49C (and GPU is 47C , GPU is the APU integrated graphics)

Answer (score -3):

I should say, 73 is a bit hot. And because the speed is 0.8 GHz, that temperature is bad. I suggest you buys desk fan.

Comment: This appears to be a comment to a 1 year old question.  Comments belong in the comment section, if you cannot submit comments, you should not submit them as answers.  Answers like this are subject to removal, and based on your current answer history, its very likely you won't be able to submit new answers in the future.  The system for quality reasons, will eventual ban you automatically from submitting answers, if you continue to submit answers like this.  Once this happens it cannot be reversed by anyone.